# How can I detect when apt-get update fails due to no network connection?

Tags: apt

I have a script which runs the command `apt-get update` but the script is unable to detect failure due to no internet.
i.e. if `apt-get` is not run with root privileges it exits with `code 100`.
so I can do a check like

```
if apt-get update
then
    echo "success!"
else
    echo "something went wrong
fi
```

But if `apt-get update` is run without an internet connect, it produces error messages, some to STDOUT, some to STDERR, e.g.

this goes to STDERR

> ...
>   W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
>   W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease
>   ...

This goes to STDOUT

```
...
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty InRelease
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com trusty Release.gpg
...
```

But ultimately it still returns an exit of `0`.
How can I detect an `apt-get upgrade` failure caused by no internet access?

Comment: "How can I detect an apt-get upgrade failure caused by no internet access?": I think this was intended to say "update" again, not "upgrade".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is fool-proof but I suppose you could test if the Internet connection is working, but I am not sure if an error is caused by no Internet connection.

```
cd [directory]
wget [just download any file aslong as you know the name.]
[ -f /[currentDir]/[filename] ] && wall "Internet Connection Is Existant" || wall "Any errors are likely caused by internet issues."
rm [file name just so it doesn't mess things up later.]
```

And you could change the "wall" to echo's I just like annoying my friends since I use SSH a lot.. (1/2 debian and 1/2 time on SSH.. On a terminal application or shell.)

Comment: thats a pretty good answer for a self confessed newb. Its close but I wouldnt use this becuase wget or similar tools can introduce their own problems. e.g. I have a curl command in a script that every 10th or so run ut just fails because there are alot of things unrelated to internet connectivity that can cause wget to fail. e.g. DNS . so on some curl commands that are important  Ill have the script just sit there retrying over and over in case of "random" failures

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stub that may work a little bit better:

```
if apt-get update 2> /tmp/apt-get-errors
then
    if grep -q "^W: Failed to fetch" /tmp/apt-get-errors
    then
      echo "success!"
    else
      echo apt-get failed to fetch
    fi
else
    echo "something went wrong
fi
rm /tmp/apt-get-errors
```

The basic idea is to catch apt-get's stderr output into a file, then search that file for known-bad patterns before declaring success.

It could be improved with the use of mktemp and possibly a better grep pattern, but I don't have a way to test apt-get right now.

Comment: thanks, I had the same  idea, I think it should work for detecting the broken internet connection. Although non-critical warnings also go to STDERR. eg if you added a repo twice. apt (assuming its connected to the internet) can still function but normally but I would want the error printed in the terminal so you might need some complicated expression like `if apt-get update 2>&1 1>/dev/tty | tee > /tmp/apt-get-errors` .Im thinking per the previous answer, of just performing a test  for internet connectivity as a separate check beforehand - and if no internet - dont even bother with `apt-get`!

Comment: you could also do something like `apt-get update 2>&1 | tee /tmp/apt-get-errors` for less typing

Answer (score 1):

I think the `--error-on=any` option does what is desired, though I have very little experience using it in practice so far. I think it's a relatively new feature of `apt` and `apt-get`:

> ```
> -eany, --error-on=any
>     Fail the update command if any error occured, even a transient one.
> ```

```
apt update -eany
apt update --error-on=any
apt-get update -eany
apt-get update --error-on=any
```

When I turn off my laptop's wifi and run `apt update --error-on=any; echo $?`, then the `echo` prints `100`.

Comment: This is the proper solution, but unfortunately, this command line option is supported only since Debian Bullseye.